# invoke method implemented to a struct after declared in main

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust so I'm not experienced with the way its object-oriented feature functions, I've followed a page but have countered in this situation where I cannot invoke ciao() from the instance of vec but instead, I have to specify by using Vet3::.. but I did assign to vec the type of struct of vet3 so shouldn't it inherit the methods? and if not how to do it in rust, thanks for your patience

```
pub struct Vet3<T>{
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T
}

impl<T> Vet3<T>{
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T, z: T) -> Self {
        Self { x,y,z }
    }
    pub fn ciao(){
        print!("hello world");
    }
}

fn main(){
    //let mut sc = ScannerAscii::new(io::stdin());
    let vect : Vet3<i64>;
    vect = Vet3::new(1, 2, 3);
    Vet3::<i64>::ciao();
    
}
```

Comment: Rust is not OO, and what you are describing is not inheritance, it's just a regular implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Instance" methods need to take a `self` in some way:

```rs
impl<T> Vet3<T>{
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T, z: T) -> Self {
        Self { x,y,z }
    }
    pub fn ciao(&self) {       // take a reference to self
        print!("hello world");
    }
}
```

Your `new` method is "static" since it doesn't have a `self` parameter. From [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html):

> In the signature for `area`, we use `&self` instead of `rectangle: &Rectangle`. The `&self` is actually short for `self: &Self`. Within an `impl` block, the type `Self` is an alias for the type that the `impl` block is for. Methods must have a parameter named `self` of type `Self` for their first parameter, so Rust lets you abbreviate this with only the name `self` in the first parameter spot.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28870e9d6656f361d15612bcb3a51cfe)